# How to make a simple javascript auto scroll widget like Google News?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a real simple widget like this:

https://news.google.com/news/rtc?pz=1&cf=all&ncl=dgEurGFdFYAMclM_T4fKHKqMP6gwM&topic=h&ar=1336324205

It is fixed width and height, and has about five or so items that scroll downwards as new items are added.

I'll be using a datasource to bind the items.

The scroller is there, it is the first item on the top - below the picture bar.

Essentially, new items come from the top and the items at the bottom scroll off. It kind of looks like something dropped from top and popped the bottom thing out - into hiding.

Comment: I see no auto-scroller there.  Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: nor can I see any auto-scroller...are you sure you know what you want?

Comment: I uploaded an image here: http://i.imgur.com/lQ30C.png